# Copying db in raw folder to existing db in android app

Tags: android, database

I have one db file in the raw folder.
I want to copy that db to my android database and use the data from that db file.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If you want to ship your app with an existing database you can do this by adding it as an asset file to your app

Comment: @juergen d Well he did. What does it matter: shipping in raw or in assets?

Comment: I scraped information from the internet and added it into the database.Now I want that database in my app

Answer (score 0):

Copy the database file from raw resource to the database folder.

Then quit your app and reboot device.

Comment: How to do it programmatically?

Comment: You did not google for android copy file from raw did you?